# hyper-v 2016 remote management

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2016

I use a host running 2012 R2, use it to manage a two hyper-v 2012r2 hosts.
I can RDP and remote PS to them ,computer management , server manager, run hyper-v manager and see all of their vms etc.

I just installed hyper-v 2016 on a new server. joined to the same domain as other hosts. Did the normal WinRM quickconfig, enable-ps remoting, Enabled Option 4 in SCONFIG.  But when I try and connect to it via Hyper-v manager from my 2012r2 host I get RPC unavailable. I can enter a remote ps session and view in server manager. All of the firewall rules that should be enabled are on to allow remote management. I've tried this with the firewall turned off. no go. dns works and net work cuse I can connect to it just not wit HVM.
Any Ideas ? is it just my host ?

Comment: Newer versions of Hyper-V Server cannot be managed by older versions of Hyper-V Manager.

Comment: For the particular combinations allowed, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/manage/remotely-manage-hyper-v-hosts.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case BUT I just tried RDP into one of the 2012 r2 HV host (full install) and added the 2016 HV server in the Hyper-manager and it connected !!!! im thinking it may be my normal host, I use to manage that has a lack of proper fw rules or something